# I have got 8 to be in game I have to pay 1 each time. I can win 2. What is a probabilty that I will have 10?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have got 8 dollars. To be in game I have to pay 1 dollar each time. I can win 2 dollars in every game with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ I have got 10 chances. If I have 0 dollars the game is over. What is a probabilty that I will have 10 dollars?

So in the best way I can win after 2 games. (win, win). 
Ahh... it's hard to write all available configuration...

Comment: Don't do it. Gambling is the first step on the road to perdition.

Comment: I only neet to calculate it! Don't worry! I will be good girl:)

Comment: If you win a game are you paid 2, or 2 plus your stake of 1?

Comment: Oh, alright. Don't stay up too late.

Comment: What is the probability of winning a game?

Comment: @almagest to be in game every time I have to pay 1. I can win 2 each time.

WillJagy OK! I would like to do it asap you it will be pleasure if you could support me!

Comment: @Henry it's 1/2, you can win or not.

Comment: random walk with boundary condition $P(S_T=10|S_0=8)$ there is a very simple way to solve this with recursive methods.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know this method. I'm wonderting if I could use Bernoulli Scheme.

Comment: @keri You are not using standard terminology. I think you mean that if you lose a game then you do not recover the 1 you paid, whereas if you win the game you are given 2, making a win of 1 (2 less the 1 you paid). So it is a fair game. Talking about a win of 2 is confusing.

Comment: Yes, it's something like you win 1 and get your 1 back so you have 2 instead of 1 if you win, or -1 in your account if you not win.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(n)$ be the chance that starting with $n$ you reach 10 before you reach 0. So $f(0)=0,f(10)=1$. Also $f(n)=\frac{1}{2}f(n-1)+\frac{1}{2}f(n+1)$ for $1\le n\le 9$. So chasing that through you find that the answer you want is $f(8)=0.8$ (and in general $f(n)=\frac{n}{10}$ for $0\le n\le 10$).

Many thanks to greggo for fixing the arithmetic!

Comment: It is also works when it is a restriction, that if you have 10 you end a game?

Comment: You asked for the chance that you got 10. Of course, you might be like most gamblers. They win a few hundred in the casino, decide it is their lucky night and go on to lose not just the few hundred they won but a few hundred more on top! Having got 10, whether you have the self-control to stop, that is another matter.

Comment: Haha true:) But it also could be a configuration like

Comment: 8, 9, 10, 9, 10, 9, 10 etc...
ANd I'm wondering is this way of counting including it, because I am not sure

Comment: If you played like that, then you would have reached 10, but decided to carry on. There is a nice theorem which shows that if you play against a casino (which has limitless cash compared to you) you will always get wiped out if you keep on playing.

Comment: But to do the math, you need a definite stopping criterion. I assumed you stop when you reach 10.

Comment: f(0) = 4/45 by the general form, not 0. So the relation f(n) = ... in your solution doesn't hold for f(1)

Comment: @greggo. You are right, I bungled the arithmetic. Now fixed, I hope.